# Assign button to row, and use it within SQL

Tags: php

So I have created a reports system, where a user can submit a report, and then administrators may log in and the reports all get pulled into a table, sorted by -ID (latest first).
I have added a button to the code that pulls out each report in the table, defined as $closeButton - with this I intend to when it's clicked, set the report as closed, (a column in the mySQl table). I have assigned the button to the ID of the report, so how can I go about making this actually work? The column in my database is called 'open', and when the value is 1 it means it's closed, (i know this is the wrong way round but yeah.. )

Code is as follows:

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($row['open'] == 1) {
        echo "<tr class=\"danger\">";
        $closeButton = "<button id='".$row['id']."' type='submit' name='openButton' class=\"text-success\"> &#10003;</button>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr>";
        $closeButton = "<button id='".$row['id']."' type='submit' name='closeButton' class=\"text-danger\">&times;</button>";
    }

    $report = "<td>". $row['id']. "</td>"."<td>". $row['dateTime']. "</td>". "<td>". $row['player']. "</td>". "<td>". $row['reason']. "</td>". "<td> ". $row['place']. "</td>". "<td><div>". $row['proof']. "</div></td>". "<td><div>". $row['comments']. "</div></td>". "<td>". $row['ip']. "<td>". $closeButton. "</td>";

    echo $report;
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: A button should usually be part of a form element, which can then post the data to your server. You should define a form and an action for it to take when it's submitted.

Comment: There's tons of places on the web to learn how to make a form, post it to a PHP file, and process the results into your MySQL database. You should probably start with the PHP docs and googling for PHP form tutorials. Stack Overflow really isn't the place for tutorials, it's for specific questions or problems with your code.